# Как изменить цвет тайтла баттона сразу для нескольких кнопок?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiview

У меня есть две одинаковые вьюхи, на каждой из них по три одинаковых Баттона. Для всех батонов есть 1 экшн. По нажатию на Баттон я хочу чтоб его тайтл менял цвет на этой вьюхе и на батоне с зеркальной вьюхи также. Для всех батонов я сделал класс customButton. Но не могу придумать как это можно реализовать чтоб не создавать кучу аутлетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать список кнопок в каком-нибудь общедоступном контроллере экрана (или даже сделать просто как глобальную переменную), чтобы при создании (init) кнопки в помещали себя в этот список, а при уничтожении (dealloc) убирали.

Тогда при нажатии на кнопку будет достаточно обойти циклом этот список и применить к нему нужные манипуляции.

К сожалению, под iOS я не кодил уже несколько лет, и ни разу на Свифте, поэтому конкретный код не подскажу. Но идея легко реализуемая.